# install_driver(ODBC) failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so' for module DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.1

Tags: perl, unixodbc

I'm using perl 5.10.1 my current server(centos 6.3). Whenever I execute Perl programs, I get following error:

```
install_driver(ODBC) failed: Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so'
for module DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
```

When I perform following command:

```
[root@test]# ldd /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBD/ODBC/ODBC.so
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fffde569000)
libodbc.so.1 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f591e49a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d25e00000)
```

I get `libodbc.so.1 is not found`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the C++ ODBC libraries. I had a similar issue when I was trying to use the XML::LibXML libraries. I my case I had to install the following C++ libraries on ubuntu.
libxml2-dev
libxml2

Here is a link to Ubuntu's package repository for libodbc.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/libodbc++4

Hope that helps.

Comment: i have already installed c++ ODBC libaries,Basically I will use centos 6.3

Comment: Ugg. I feel your pain. Their FAQ says the order you install is important. 
http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.39/FAQ#What_is_the_ODBC_driver_manager?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 64 bit versions (or build them yourself) of unixODBC and unixODBC-dev packages. I am surprised you've got DBD::ODBC installed without having them already as the build process needs them. So, the question is how did you install DBD::ODBC?

Comment: Installed unixODBC at localDir using ./configure --prefix=/home/userl/unixODBC. And then I installed DBD::ODBC perl Makefile.PL -o /home/user/unixODBC PREFIX=/home/user/perl5. Although few tests failed but install went fine. Finally got ODBC.so' for module DBD::ODBC: libodbc.so.2.. I have this: libodbc.so.2 => not found

Not sure where I can find unixODBC and unixODBC-dev 64 bit versions.

Comment: Resolved after adding unixODBC path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, by: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/unixODBC/lib